# Basis for column space & Find it without elimination. [GStrang P192 3.6.14]

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

> On P187, Prof Strang writes:
>   The columns of $REF(A)$ often end in zeros. The columns of $A$ don't often end in zeros. The column spaces are different, but their dimensions are the same: $r$. So $C(A) \neq C(REF(A))$.

$\Large{{1.}}$ Are there deeper intuitive reasons why $C(A) \neq C(REF(A))$? The totality of the elementary row operations produce the linear combinations which link the row spaces (but not the rows). Why doesn't this argument apply to column spaces?

$\Large{{2.}}$ I ask $1$ because I don't see the basis for the column space of $A$. How does this answer behold it?

> **Answer:** $\{ \, (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \}.$ We happen to have $C(A) = C(U) = \mathbb{R^3}.$

Answer (score 1):

The jist of number 1 is that there is an asymmetry between columns and rows here. The *row* echelon form is obtained through a squence of elementary *row* operations. These operations are designed to preserve the rowspace of the matrix, but there is no guarantee that they will also preserve the columnspace. Indeed, in many cases the elementary row operations will act to change the columnspace of the matrix. For example, consider

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},\ \ \ \ \mathrm{rref}(A) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
In this case, the columnspace of $A$ is spanned by $(1,\ 1)^\mathrm{T}$ whereas the columsnace of the reduced row echelon form is spanned by $(1, 0)^\mathrm{T}$.

So instead of asking for a deep intuitive reason why $C(A)\neq C(\mathrm{ref}(A))$, a better question would be to ask why you expect such a relationship in the first place.

What *is* true however is that the elementary row operations will preserve linear dependence relations for the columns. That is to say, a given set of columns for $A$ will be linearly independent if and only if the corresponding columns of the reduced echelon form is linearly independent. This means that a basis for columnspace of the echelon form (easily found) will *correspond* to a basis of the columnspace for $A$ and vice versa.

In the given example, you can see that the first three columns of $\mathrm{ref}(A)$ forms a basis for the columnspace of $\mathrm{ref}(A)$. What this means is that the corresponding columns, i.e. the first three columns of $A$, will form a basis for the columnspace of $A$. You don't know what those columns are of course, but you do know that they must form a basis.

In this case, we know that the columnspace of $A$ is $3$ dimensional (since we know the basis contains three vectors) and so we know it must be $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself (since the columnspace is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$). This allows us to pick any basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a basis for the columnspace, and Strang chose the standard basis vectors. If the columnspace were not full dimensional then we would not be so lucky, and in general we would not be able to tell what the columnspace of $A$ is when given only the columnspace of $\mathrm{ref}(A)$.